# Identities with dirac deltas

Tags: physics, dirac-delta

How are you supposed to verify or derive common physics text 'identities' involving dirac deltas like
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \mbox{sign}(t) \frac {\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \delta(|\mathbf x|^2-t^2) 
= 
2 \pi \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \delta(\mathbf x)
$$
Replacing delta with things like $\lim_{a\to 0} \frac{1}{a\sqrt \pi} e^{-(x/a)^2}$ gets me nowhere. Can this be seen just from test functions?

Comment: The (mathematical) definition of a Dirac delta is as a linear functional on test functions.  If an identity such as $\lim_{t \to 0} A_t(x) = B(x)$ is
true, where $A_t$ and $B$ are distributions (and the "limit" is understood in the weak topology), it must be that $\lim_{t \to 0} \int A_t(x) \phi(x)\; dx = \int B(x) \phi(x)$ for all test functions $\phi$.

Comment: What you really need is the notion of pull-back distributions and their derivatives. Wikipedia unfortunately does not have a full description, I would suggest visiting one of the standard textbooks on distribution theory (Friendlander-Joshi for example).

Comment: Does the above identity even make sense as a weak derivative though? Won't multiplying by a discontinuous function like sign$(t)$ ruin test functions?